# Suction cup on car dashboard

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, pressure, air

I have this suction cup to hold dashcam in car. When I leave car in  sun suction fails and camera falls down.
Did camera fall because air got heated under suction and expanded or plastic/rubber expansion?

If i fix suction at that hot windshield will it be strongest suction, as air can cool only from this temp ?

Comment: probably just the rubber or plastic gets to hot and deforms.